# About Xcode4 and C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

Since I have Xcode4, I can't use the refactoring capabilities of XCode with C++ project.
Is there a way around that or does the only language Xcode cares about is Object C ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's refactoring tools currently support only C and Objective-C. They don't support C++.

Comment: It's really frustrating, I think I'll move to Eclipse. Thanks.